# Is it true that "A Java Iterator is an Abstract Data Type"?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, iterator

I'm trying to deepen my understanding on this, the only thing I know for sure is that Iterator is an interface in Java.

I've been reading CS literature, for example [here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/common/kathi-notes/adts.html) and [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs367-1/readings/Introduction/index.html) and looking for similar questions here.

All I've come up is just a bit confusing to me: I read, for example, that *"abstract datatypes simply summarize names and types of operations (in Java, this means interfaces)"* or *"each ADT corresponds to a class (or Java interface) and the operations on the ADT are the class/interface's public methods"*. Some people even confuse ADTs with abstract classes.

So, may I state that an Iterator is an abstract data type?

Comment: I think this is a good question. It is something I've never thought about before, and definitely applies to object oriented design and analysis.

Comment: Related: [Are terms “abstraction” and “abstract data types” connected with each other?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/328422/118878), but I'm not sure if this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Another related question: [Understanding Abstract Data Types](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/38642/118878)

Comment: Which ultimately points to [Abstract Data Type and Data Structure](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148747/118878), but again I'm not 100% sure these are duplicates.

Comment: Funnily enough, I found that the authors that add "simply" to their explanations more often are also the ones which are usually less knowledgeable about their subject. Those definitions of ADT's don't really help understanding the concept.

Answer (score 6):

#### A Tale of Abstractions

There's a lot of confusion about this on the Internet, but the term is quite technical, and according to the Cook [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ewcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) (referenced in the [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/38675/275536) liked to by Greg Burghardt), it essentially boils down to this.

OOP Objects (and the related static typing mechanisms, including classes, abstract classes and interface types) and ADTs represent *two different approaches* to data abstraction. Cook calls the OOP approach "procedural abstraction" - I'll come back to that later. The two have different strengths and weaknesses.

To understand this, think about the underlying concrete data structures (the *representations*), the operations on them, and the client code (that calls these operations). The OOP approach makes it easy to add new representations (new derived classes, or new implementations of an interface), as long as you don't change the set of operations. The term for this is the *public interface*. Don't confuse this with *interface types* (declared via the `interface` keyword); in this more broad meaning, the public interface is the set of public members (public methods, properties, fields, events). On the other hand, adding new operations is difficult - you have to hunt down all existing different derivatives and change their implementation details to make sure they all support the changed interface.

This is a "procedural abstraction" in the sense that the public interface defines a contract between clients and different implementations, a contract that abstracts away the actual functions (procedures) that are being called. The interface defines a more generalized notion of an operation - it defines *what* the operation *means*, what it *does*, but not exactly *how* it does it. When you call a method on an object through a variable of a more abstract type, you are expecting it to do perform this operation (as defined by this contract, and as explained in the documentation), but you don't know for sure which concrete function on which class will get called - the underlying language mechanism dispatches the call for you.

Now, with ADTs, it's a bit different. There's typically a finite, *limited* set of different representations (different underlying data structures). These are all then deemed to be different forms of the same abstract data type (ADT). It is abstract in the sense that you are arranging things so that you can use these different, concrete data structures to in a way that lets you pretend that it's all the same type. So far, that doesn't sound that much different from OOP. As before, client code never mentions the concrete representations (except when the constructors are called); all of it is written in terms of this ADT. However, the operations on the ADT *aren't* themselves abstract in the same way OOP operations are. Each ADT function internally provides an implementation for every possible representation. There's basically a switch statement in there, that switches on the concrete type, or if not, then there's some language feature that does roughly the same thing. So, in ADTs, clients can ignore the actual concrete type (concrete representation) *because* each function has a part that deals with any particular representation, and so is guaranteed to work.

This makes it easy to add new operations - you just add a new functions, and you write a bit of logic for each possible representation, or rely on existing functions and treat the data abstractly yourself. Adding new representations, however, is hard, because you then break the aforementioned guarantee; to maintain it, you have to find all functions on the ADT and implement support for the new case.

That means that even though concrete representations are hidden from client code, they are also a part of the ADT contract when it comes to extensions (to adding new operations).

As with any decoupling, in both cases there's an abstraction in between that represents a certain contract between the two components. They get to be decoupled *precisely because* they are both coupled to that contract, to the abstraction (which is a more generalized representation of the interaction between the two components). If the contract is broken, so is the decoupling.

You'll encounter ADTs more in functional languages, where the "switch" on the representation happens via pattern matching. But also, primitive types, like `float` can be considered ADTs as well (though internal to the language), at least in the context of certain operations, because there are different underlying representations - e.g. there are *special* bit patterns that represent -inf, +inf, NaN, etc., and when you use the normal arithmetic operations, you don't have to examine for these special cases, the operations can handle these by themselves.

It's not all about the type system though; you can use these ideas to design your own abstractions outside of the type system. One example is the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern. While it's often described as a way to do multiple dispatch, it can also be seen as an implementation of an ADT: the different Element derivatives are the different representations, and different Visitors are different operations. Note the similarities: it is easy to add new visitors, but since each visitor handles every element, it is hard to add new elements. Another way to do it is to write operations that in terms of handles - instead of an object or a concrete data structure, an operation takes in a *handle* (e.g., an index of some sort), and then uses it internally to discover the concrete type and find some data structure somewhere. This is probably something you'd do under special circumstances, though - e.g., the motivation may be to increase performance by taking control over how data is stored to ensure cache friendliness.

Finally to answer your question; Iterator, as implemented in Java, is not an ADT in this sense; but in general it should be possible to implement iterators as ADTs.

---

#### What part of Iterator in Java doesn't meet the definition?

It's because of the *kind* of abstraction used here. It's the "procedural abstraction" (the OOP kind of abstraction): the [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface represents a "thing you can iterate over" (a collection), that supports a certain set of abstract operations (most importantly, `next` and `hasNext`).

It's *easy to add new representations* (new implementations of Iterator) - you just implement the interface. Here, "new representation" refers to things like the state that the iterator keeps internally, and the exact details of how it goes about the iteration: you can vary the collection over which it iterates, the order in which it does so, how it keeps track of all of that, etc. And you don't have to make changes to client code,  as long as it relies solely on the Iterator interface. Java's foreach loop ("enhanced for-loop") makes use of Iterator behind the scenes; it can work with custom collections if they implement the [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, which in turn provides the foreach loop with a way to obtain an Iterator.

More to the point, if Java came up with new collections and new iterators for them (new concrete representations of Iterator), that wouldn't affect other people's code - it's just a new option that people can make use of if they want to. If, on the other hand, they changed the foreach loop to *require* a new operation on the Iterable interface (the assumption here is that there's no reasonable default implementation), than that would be a breaking change - anyone who implemented Iterable & Iterator to provide support for the foreach loop would have to go back and change their code. Hopefully, this gives some context to "easy" vs "hard"; it's not merely about one being more inconvenient then the other for the programmer, but rather about the interaction between the client code and library code in the face of change, especially once the latter has been released "out there". New implementations are adding new behavior, sure, but it within the confines of the abstract operations (it's conceptually the same set of high-level operations), and client code is written in a way that *expects this*.

Comment: Very detailed answer up to the part about answering the question.  Maybe it's in there but could you explain what part of Iterator in Java doesn't meet the definition?

Comment: I'm struggling with something here: "This makes it easy to add new operations - you just add a new functions" then later we have: "But also, primitive types, like float can be considered ADTs as well", I can't 'add' operations to float.  I can create things that work with `float` but I can do that with any type.  Perhaps I'm missing something basic.

Comment: @JimmyJames: regarding floats - this is why I added "though internal to the language"; the programmer cannot add completely new operations (except if they can be written entirely in terms of existing ones), but the language designers can (in principle). In this case, it's an implementation detail of the language, but the concept can also be directly supported by the type system (letting programmers use it to express their own types), or it can be applied at design level (by relying on data, or by "repurposing" language features in some clever way).

Comment: @JimmyJames: "Maybe it's in there but could you explain what part of Iterator in Java doesn't meet the definition?" - I've edited the answer.

Comment: The definition of ADT used in the referenced paper doesn't fit what I learned in my "algorithms & data structures" course in university. And your answer, all that stuff about "finite, limited set of representations" , sounds more like **arithmetic data types** (sum types, Haskell's `data`, Rust's `enum`) hidden behind an interface, than ADTs as I understand them. So while this is a well-written answer, I disagree with the fundamental definition behind it.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'd be really interested to see a resolution to this disagreement.  I think I've got my head more-or-less around the way ADTs are defined in the paper but I'm bothered by the idea that the academia would conflate this with OO.  I mean, the ADT concept described there is kind of shit.  Sure, for really basic ubiquitous types, sure (but why do we need different representations for those anyway?) but in general, some sort of monster switch statement that everyone is hacking on seems like a pure distillation of bad coding practices.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm going to write my own answer. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Upon a closer reading of the paper, I revise my opinion. The paper is sound. But I believe the answer here is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of the section on ADTs, though going into it is too big a topic for comments.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: If you mean that it's similar to *algebraic* data types, that's not a coincidence - the OOP (messages) vs ADTs in this sense are two approaches to data abstraction (there's a third one, table based, there's a chapter on all somewhere in [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), I'll try to find it); the ADT idea was historically easier to formalize into a mathematical type theory as an algebraic structure, and this (in part) lead the language/compiler researchers developing algebraic data types, and the formalism was later on expanded.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Also, the rigorous algebr. DT formalism is great for a type system, but as an informal idea, product types and sum types are both algebraic, and classes (specifically, the way state is defined) in OOP represent product types - so in that informal sense the ideas are somewhat orthogonal (the kind of abstraction, vs the structure described by the set of values the state can assume).

Comment: @SebastianRedl: BTW, sometimes people use "abstract data types" in a less formal way to mean "abastract types", so what you've learned at university is not necessarily wrong. This kind of ambiguity of terms is more common than you think, you can find examples in practically any field; so, I guess it's best to be aware that there are these two distinct meanings and to adopt one or the other depending on context.

Comment: @JimmyJames: "monster switch statement [...] seems like a pure distillation of bad coding practices" - in general, yes, but this is can be a result of trying to emulate ADTs in a language that has limited support (different paradigm, different features). But everything in design is a tradeoff, and sometimes the tradeoff is to do something "hackish" in order to gain something else. E.g., take data-oriented ECS design in game industry; they are essentially giving up on OOP in order to have direct control over storage and composition of instances (components), mostly for performance reasons.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Here's the [chapter](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_sec_2.4) I mentioned earlier. They don't use the same terminology, but they do describe the same things. So the ideas are fairly old. Section 2.4.2., Tagged data, talks about ADTs (scroll down to code under the paragraph "Each generic selector..."). Ch 2.4.3, Data-Directed programming talks about the table based design, and the Message passing section at the bottom talks about OOP (without having OOP facilities in the language - so the same idea, but as a pattern).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I don't mean to argue that OO is perfect.  Not be a long shot.  The introduction of functional concepts in to Java, for example, has vastly improved it's usability and conciseness.  What gives me a little consternation is this assertion: "Academic computer science has generally not accepted the
fact that there is another form of data abstraction besides abstract data types."  If the Cook's arguments hold, it seems like a pretty major failure of 'academic computer science'.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I look forward to seeing you elaborate on your position.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So, may I state that an Iterator is an abstract data type?

An ADT is a collection of data and a set of operations that may be performed on that data. An iterator is composed of a set of data to iterate and a set of operations for performing that iteration. Importantly, those operations do not define how the operator is performed. So an iterator - in general terms - is an ADT.

**But** the answer to the question in your title, "*Is it true that “A Java Iterator is an Abstract Data Type”?*", is "no". The Java `Iterator` is an interface, ie it only defines the set of operations, not the collection. And in general, "Java iterators" are implementations of that interface, so they define how the behaviours are performed. They aren't abstract in that regard so aren't ADTs.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right ADTs are **abstract** types. This means they are not expressed or implemented in any language. Java interface is already a specific representation of some possible abstract Iterator written or depicted on paper, on desk or as part of UML diagram for example.

But java.util.Iterator is definitely a very close representation of what possible Iterator should be. Many other languages have another representations of iterator. Cpp has std:: iterator for most common case. So iterator is what we talk about as a concept, what we can discuss. It's not what you use in day-to-day work in any particular language. Moreover it doesn't matter can you call smth in any certain construct as ADT or something else. It should just *work as expected* and that's all. Java iterators do what they should do. And nobody cares about naming and terms.

What else I can say about ADT is that it is outdated concept for modern computer science. ADTs cover just one aspect of program engineering - working with data. This is all about what is already implemented and reused via higher-level abstractions. Data abstractions are nowadays used mostly in just one layer of computer systems - DAO, data access objects. Other layers work mostly with other types of abstractions, eg actors, processes, strategies. So it's not productive to discuss naming of abstractions that already have thousands of implementations in existing code base for tens of years.